# How many pairs of solutions does this integer equation has?

Tags: number-theory

$m, n\in \mathcal{Z}$, how many solutions(finite or infinite?) does this equation have:

$$
(m+n)^2+2mn+2(m+n)=0
$$

I've found $(0,0),(0,-2),(-2,0)$, are they complete?

Comment: If you plot the equation here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator, you've got your answer.

Comment: A quick check with Wolfram Alpha yields several families of integer solutions (in a rather complicated parametrization), so have a look there to find other solutions. Examples are $(-24,6),(-330,1230)$ or $(-63954,17136)$

Comment: @BartRutten How would that help? You would have to zoom out many, many times to get all the solutions.

Comment: [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4dncegevys) is a better graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite, becose it is Pell equation $(3 n + 1)^2 - 3 (2 n + m + 1)^2 = -2$

Some first pairs $(n,m)$:

```
(0, 0)
(0, -2)
(-2, 0)
(-2, 6)
(6, -2)
(6, -24)
(-24, 6)
(-24, 88)
(88, -24)
(88, -330)
(-330, 88)
(-330, 1230)
(1230, -330)
(1230, -4592)
(-4592, 1230)
(-4592, 17136)
(17136, -4592)
(17136, -63954)
(-63954, 17136)
(-63954, 238678)
(238678, -63954)
(238678, -890760)
(-890760, 238678)
(-890760, 3324360)
(3324360, -890760)
(3324360, -12406682)
(-12406682, 3324360)
(-12406682, 46302366)
(46302366, -12406682)
(46302366, -172802784)
(-172802784, 46302366)
(-172802784, 644908768)
(644908768, -172802784)
(644908768, -2406832290)
```